# How do I disable a bluetooth adapter and install a new one in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, usb, bluetooth, ubuntu-13.04

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 on a Macbook Pro (8.2). I have a faulty bluetooth antenna that I am not interested in paying to fix. In windows I have a usb bluetooth dongle and I just keep the built in bluetooth disabled.

However, I am new to Ubuntu/Linux and I can't quite figure out how to disable the internal bluetooth adapter in Ubuntu, and setup the USB adapter in its place.

The USB Adapter is an Asus BT-400, which apparently runs the BCM20702A0 Broadcom chipset. Which my limited googling suggests *is* compatible with linux.

That being said, the primary goal here is to completely disable the internal bluetooth so that it's never active. Getting the dongle working is a bonus, and I can simply buy a different linux compatible one if necessary.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Same situation here.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not, and my install managed to bork itself, thus ending my attempts.